# How can I protect url paths with only client's ID and secret?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to configure a RESTFul web service with Spring and I've already configured OAuth. So I got a couple of pages that requires a user's OAuth token. However, I have some pages that are for anonymous access like signup or forgot-password for example.

Pages like www.mywebsite.com/api/doStuff [GET/POST] are protected by requiring a valid OAuth token but how can I protect pages like www.mywebsite.com/api/signup [POST] with **only** the **client's ID** and **secret** with a header **Authorization: Basic [Base64EncodedString]** ?

I don't want those "unsecured pages" to be accessed by anyone but the client like a mobile app (iOS/Android) for example.

Here's my configure(HttpSecurity) method in my ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter class

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
    .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**")
.and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/doStuff", "/api/getOtherStuff").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read') and hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    .antMatchers("/api/signup").access("#oauth2.isClient()") // Not working like I thought...
.and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use basic auth for some resources you're probably better off creating a separate filter chain (i.e. a new `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`) and set it up there with rules to match only the paths you want to protect that way.